# Control not being pushed or unshifted into form array Angular 6

Tags: regex, angular, formarray

I have a variable string in the format like this: `id={ID}&sdv={sdvsdbsdb.:}`

I need to get the contents between the two `{` `}` and push it into a form group array.

The pattern that I am using to match this is `\{([a-zA-Z\:\.]*?)\}`

Originally I was using a simpler regex `\{(.*?)\}` but the issue with this is that if you take `id={ID}&sdv={sdvsdbsdb.:}` and remove the first `}` it will match the entire string from the first `{` to the first `}`.

The function that I am using to do this is this:

```
while ((matched_parameter = pattern.exec(redirect_string)) != null) {
    let redirect_found: boolean = false;
    for (let index in parameters.controls) {
        if (parameters.controls[index].value['key'] == matched_parameter[1]) {
            redirect_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!redirect_found && matched_parameter[1] != '') {
            (<FormArray>this.form_group.get('parameters')).controls.unshift(this.form_builder.group({
                "key": matched_parameter[1],
                "internal": false,
                "source": "record",
                "field": "panelist_id",
                "varies_by_status": false
            }));
    }
}
```

This does work and match any of the parameters that arent already in the list but when it says that it added to the array the new value doesnt appeare.

Comment: Your question is very unclear ; please be more specific and detail what you're trying to achieve. Best way to do that is to make a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.io

Comment: @trichetriche I updated the question and hope it helps. Unfortunately I'm not able to use stackblitz.io I am never able to get projects to load whether I create one or load one someone else made